# Insertar imagen

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hola chicos me gustaría que desde este input type=file al eligir una imagen me la devuelva en la siguiente página upload.php mostrándomela.
El objetivo es que la imagen que el usuario elija en el seleccionar archivo que genera el type file y al darle al botón submit se muestre la imagen en el archivo upload.php.
Muchas gracias a todos!

````
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <h2>Puja i comparteix les teves imatges!</h2> 
        <p>Una vegada seleccionada la imatge clica a "comença a pujar".</p>
        <p>Arrossega i deixa anar sobre "Seleccionar arxiu" la imatge desitjada!</p>
        <p>La mida límit és de 32mb.</p> 
        <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"  value="COMIENZA A SUBIR" name="Enviar">
        </form>
    </div>
</body>```

Archivo upload.php:
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="container" id="imatge">
            <!-- Aqui me gustaria que se mostrara la imagen --> 
        </div>
        <div class="container" id="dadesimatge">
            <!-- texto -->
        </div>
    </div>
````

Comment: Te olvidaste de agregar el código de `upload.php`.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Ya probaste `src="variable_imagen"`

Comment: Ya pero como hago para que el src pille la imagen que yo he seleccionado. PD: He intentado explicar lo mejor arriba.

Comment: Hasta ahora solo nuestras el código html, y te falta la función que es para mostrar tu imágen.   Querés mostrar en `id="imatge"` que está en la misma página o en otra página?

Comment: Narciso la idea es mostrarla en la otra página, el problema es que acabo de empezar con javascript y no se hacer funciones

Answer (score 0):

Me es difícil comprender la pregunta, pero deduzco que se quiere mostrar la imagen seleccionada por el `input` en el div `id="imatge"`.

```css
 

#imatge img {
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
}
```

```html
 

<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload"> 
<hr> 
<div class="container" id="imatge"></div>
  
<script>
document.getElementById("fileToUpload").onchange = function(e) {   
 
 // Creamos el objeto de la clase FileReader 
 let reader = new FileReader();   
 
 // Leemos el archivo subido y se lo pasamos a nuestro fileReader   
 reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);   
 
 // Le decimos que cuando este listo ejecute el código interno 
 reader.onload = function(){ 
  
  let preview = document.getElementById('imatge'), 
  image = document.createElement('img'); 
  image.src = reader.result; 
  preview.innerHTML = ''; 
  preview.append(image);
 
 }; 

}
</script>
```